# Need to add If (Test-Connection) cmdlet

Tags: ping

Is it possible to add the If (Test-Connection) cmdlet to this script? I want to ping the host first 
the run the script if the host its on.

```
`enter code here`

    $sb = { write-host "$env:computername"

    Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\McAfee\AVSolution\DS\ -Recurse | ForEach-Object {

    Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath
    }
    }
    $Results = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb -ComputerName (Get-Content -Path 'C:\computers.txt')

    #Show output to screen

    Write-Output $Results

    $Results | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\computers.CSV' -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: "Is it possible to add the If (Test-Connection) cmdlet to this script?" - Yes it is. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-7) for examples (esp example 5). Consider attempting to add this yourself and if it does not work update your question with your attempt (currently its not clear what you want to happen if the host does not respond).

Comment: I was able to to add the if (Test-Connection $env:computername -Quiet -Count 1 -EA 0) and it seems to do the trick